# Rapids / docker: could not select device driver "" with capabilities: [[gpu]]

Tags: docker, gpu, nvidia, rapids

I'm new to Rapids, and rarely have had a good experience with conda. So I'm trying to work with a containerized version. I'm new to Docker, and the combination of unknowns leaves me unable to sort things out.

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 server,

```
# uname -v
#30~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 17 06:14:09 UTC 2020
```

on which I installed a fresh version of Docker

```
# apt-get install docker docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
# docker --version
Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b7f0
```

This machine has cuda v10.2 installed

```
# nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Oct_23_19:24:38_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.2, V10.2.89
```

and Python v3.6.9

```
# python3 --version
Python 3.6.9
```

As shown in the [NVIDIA Container Toolkit Quickstart](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker#quickstart) section, I install the nvidia-docker list to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

```
# curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add -
# curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu18.04/nvidia-docker.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-docker.list
```

explicitly substituting `ubuntu18.04` for $distribution, since that is the [Ubuntu equivalent for Linux Mint 19.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint_version_history#Linux_Mint_Debian_Edition_release_history).

Following the Start Container and Notebook Server instructions in [RAPIDS - Open GPU Data Science](https://hub.docker.com/r/rapidsai/rapidsai/), I pulled the 0.13-cuda10.2-runtime-ubuntu18.04-py3.6 runtime.

```
# docker pull rapidsai/rapidsai:0.13-cuda10.2-runtime-ubuntu18.04-py3.6
```

A long time, and several GB later, all seemed to be OK. (No warnings or error messages.) Furthermore, it looks like the image was registered with Docker.

```
# docker images -a
REPOSITORY          TAG                                       IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
rapidsai/rapidsai   0.13-cuda10.2-runtime-ubuntu18.04-py3.6   c7440af853b5        4 days ago          9.26GB
rapidsai/rapidsai   cuda10.2-runtime-ubuntu18.04-py3.6        c7440af853b5        4 days ago          9.26GB
```

However, I next tried to start up the notebook server:

```
# docker run --gpus all --rm -it -p 8888:8888 -p 8787:8787 -p 8786:8786 \
       rapidsai/rapidsai:cuda10.0-runtime-ubuntu18.04-py3.6
docker: Error response from daemon: could not select device driver "" with capabilities: [[gpu]].
```

This seems surprising, as there are two GTX 1080 Ti GPUs detected

```
# nvidia-smi
Fri May  8 16:41:57 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.33.01    Driver Version: 440.33.01    CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 108...  On   | 00000000:08:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 21%   38C    P8    10W / 250W |      1MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 108...  On   | 00000000:42:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 23%   42C    P8    10W / 250W |      1MiB / 11177MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

After cleaning things up

```
# docker system prune -a
# apt-get purge docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc
```

I re-installed docker and pulled the rapidsai image again. The result was unchanged.

Is there a conflict with the NVIDIA Driver Version: 440.33.01?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks for trying out RAPIDS.  Did you happen to install `nvidia-container-toolkit`?  https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker#quickstart.  I didn't see that in your steps and missing it could cause that issue.  It's in our prerequisites on https://rapids.ai/start.html

Comment: And don't forget to restart docker after the installation: `sudo systemctl restart docker`

Answer (score 3):

I just followed the steps in this [pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61689954/rapids-docker-could-not-select-device-driver-with-capabilities-gpu); and it works fine:

To uninstall a previous nvidia-docker package, issue these commands:

```bash
docker volume ls -q -f driver=nvidia-docker | xargs -r -I{} -n1 docker ps -q -a -f volume={} | xargs -r docker rm –f
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-docker
```

To install the NVIDIA-GPU Docker Container Toolkit, you first need to add package repositories:

```bash
distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID)
curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add -
curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/$distribution/nvidia-docker.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-docker.list
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-container-toolkit
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Then verify the nvidia-smi install with the latest official CUDA image:

```bash
sudo docker run -it --rm --gpus all nvidia/cuda:9.0-base nvidia-smi
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
sudo apt install -y nvidia-docker2
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [NVIDIA CUDA/WSL 2 documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html#installing-docker):

> Use the Docker installation script to install Docker for your choice of WSL 2 Linux distribution. Note that NVIDIA Container Toolkit does not yet support [Docker Desktop WSL 2](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/) backend.